# changing the behaviour of control signals at startup

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, signals, stty

I am trying to change the default behavior of the control signals with `stty`.
Signals like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+D, Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+\. Can any one give me idea about how to disable and enable these signals on console with `stty`.

Comment: More correctly they are _special characters_ that trigger the _line discipline_ to send signals.

Answer (score 1):

You can "trap" commands (and key combinations) with `trap`:

```
trap "echo CTRL+C not allowed" 2
```

Now when I use `CTRL+C` in the terminal I get this message:

```
CTRL+C not allowed
```

Or, just `trap "" 2` if you simply want to trap `CTRL+C` without printing anything.

To clear a trap, simply do:

```
trap - 2
```

Read the man page for trap **[here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trap.1p.html)**. More information about signals and traps can be found **[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm)**.

Comment: no i dont want to show any type of messages nor allow these signals to interrupt my program for some time. After some time again i need to enable these signals.

Comment: @Kumar2080 See my edit. And please **read the information** in the links I posted.

Answer (score 0):

trap will not work on CTRL+Z ,when you provide CTRL+Z the handler will not
execute and your console gets non-interactive